Highcharts- series inside navigator not displaying with smaller x-axis values
I'm facing an issue with the chart's x-axis configuration when in minutes. When the x-axis values are in milliseconds, the series inside the navigator displays correctly. However, when the x-axis is in minutes, the interval becomes very small, causing the series inside the navigator to not display.
Here are the fiddle examples illustrating the issue:
Fiddle with milliseconds (working)- https://jsfiddle.net/gopalsingh0707/2yzm0en1/22/
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'x',
            events: {
                render: function() {
                    if (this.navigator) {
                        this.navigator.render();
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Numeric X-Axis Labels with Custom Range Selector and Navigator'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'linear', // Ensure the x-axis is treated as numeric
            title: {
                text: 'Numeric Values'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 2); // Format with 2 decimal places
                },
                rotation: 0, // Rotation of labels
                align: 'center', // Alignment of labels
                style: {
                    fontSize: '10px', // Font size of labels
                    color: '#000000' // Color of labels
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Value'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Data',
            data: 
            
[[0.0, 0.062155798], [0.39999998, 0.36257562], [0.79999995, 0.9530556], [1.1999999, 1.03593], [1.5999999, 1.3881462], [1.9999999, 1.4710206], [2.3999999, 1.3674276], [2.7999997, 1.6056917], [3.1999998, 1.5435357], [3.6, 1.6160507], [3.9999998, 1.8232368], [4.3999996, 2.030422], [4.7999997, 2.196172], [5.2, 2.08222], [5.5999994, 2.113298], [5.9999995, 2.040782], [6.3999996, 2.123656], [6.7999997, 2.330842], [7.2, 2.341202], [7.5999994, 2.351562], [7.9999995, 2.5173101], [8.4, 2.299764], [8.799999, 2.38264], [9.2, 2.548388], [9.599999, 2.496592], [9.999999, 2.237608], [10.4, 2.237608], [10.799999, 2.289406], [11.199999, 2.310124], [11.599999, 2.040782], [11.999999, 2.08222]...]

            type: 'line',
            boostThreshold: 5000, // Boost module threshold
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            },
          //  showInNavigator: true // Show in navigator
        }],
        navigator: {
            enabled: true,
            adaptToUpdatedData: true,
            xAxis: {
                type: 'linear', // Ensure the navigator x-axis is also numeric
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 2); // Match the main chart's format
                    }
                }
            },
            series: {
                dataGrouping: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        scrollbar: {
            enabled: true,
          
        }
    });

Fiddle with min. (Not working)- https://jsfiddle.net/gopalsingh0707/j8yaf1nw/78/
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'x',
            events: {
                render: function() {
                    if (this.navigator) {
                        this.navigator.render();
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Numeric X-Axis Labels with Custom Range Selector and Navigator'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'linear', // Ensure the x-axis is treated as numeric
            title: {
                text: 'Numeric Values'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 2); // Format with 2 decimal places
                },
                rotation: 0, // Rotation of labels
                align: 'center', // Alignment of labels
                style: {
                    fontSize: '10px', // Font size of labels
                    color: '#000000' // Color of labels
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Value'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Data',
            data: 
            
[[0, 0.062155798], [0.000007, 0.36257562], [0.000013, 0.9530556], [0.00002, 1.03593], [0.000027, 1.3881462], [0.000033, 1.4710206], [0.00004, 1.3674276], [0.000047, 1.6056917], [0.000053, 1.5435357], [0.00006, 1.6160507], [0.000067, 1.8232368], [0.000073, 2.030422], [0.00008, 2.196172], [0.000087, 2.08222], [0.000093, 2.113298], [0.0001, 2.040782], [0.000107, 2.123656], [0.000113, 2.330842], [0.00012, 2.341202], [0.000127, 2.351562], [0.000133, 2.5173101], [0.00014, 2.299764], [0.000147, 2.38264], [0.000153, 2.548388], [0.00016, 2.496592], [0.000167, 2.237608], [0.000173, 2.237608], [0.00018, 2.289406], [0.000187, 2.310124], [0.000193, 2.040782], [0.0002, 2.08222], [0.000207, 2.196172], [0.000213, 2.134016]...]

            ,
            
            type: 'line',
            boostThreshold: 5000, // Boost module threshold
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            },
          //  showInNavigator: true // Show in navigator
        }],
        navigator: {
            enabled: true,
            adaptToUpdatedData: true,
            xAxis: {
                type: 'linear', // Ensure the navigator x-axis is also numeric
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 2); // Match the main chart's format
                    }
                }
            },
            series: {
                dataGrouping: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        scrollbar: {
            enabled: true,
          
        }
    });

Any help with resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!
I've tried with all possible navigator attributes such as Adjust x-axis Formatting, Set x-axis Type etc.

To solve this, disable dataGrouping for navigaor series:
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u63y0pm4/

Thank you so much. It is working as expected now.

the series inside navigator is not displaying correctly for 1,53,000 data points. https://jsfiddle.net/gopalsingh0707/b3xvh0zf/12/      You see here the blurred line inside the navigator, which further go away once you zoom in/out. Can you please help me here to fix this? Thanks.

The answer will be provided in the created thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78672049/series-inside-navigator-not-displaying-with-larger-data-set
