Series inside navigator not displaying with larger data set
I'm facing an issue with the Highchart navigator. The series inside the navigator displays correctly with smaller datasets, such as 4-5k data points. However, with a very large dataset of 153,000 data points, the series appears blurred and then disappears when zooming in or out.
Here's a sample demonstrating the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/gopalsingh0707/qm0sfrpx/5/
Highcharts.chart('container', 
  
  { "chart" : { events: { render() { let chart = this; if (chart.customImg) { chart.customImg.destroy(); } chart.customImg =  chart.renderer.image("../javax.faces.resource/images/volume.png.xhtml?ln=roma-layout", chart.plotWidth + chart.plotLeft-54, 12, 25, 20).on("click", function() { generateWaveAudio(); }).attr({ zIndex: 100  }).css({ cursor: "pointer" }).add(); } }, "zoomType" : "x" , "height": 242},  "boost" : { useGPUTranslations: true }, "series" : [ { showInNavigator: true, boostThreshold: 5000, lineWidth: 1, states: { hover: { lineWidth: 1 }  }, "data" :[[0, 40.30661], [2.1E-7, -146.0206], [4.2E-7, 43.828434], [6.2E-7, 43.828434], [8.3E-7, 43.828434], [0.00000104, 40.30661], [0.00000125, 43.828434], [0.00000146, 43.828434], [0.00000167, -146.0206], [0.00000187, -146.0206], [0.00000208, -146.0206], [0.00000229, 40.30661], [0.0000025, -146.0206], [0.00000271, -146.0206], [0.00000292, 34.286007], [0.00000312, -146.0206], [0.00000333, 49.849033], [0.00000354, 40.30661], [0.00000375, -146.0206], [0.00000396, -146.0206], [0.00000417, 43.828434], [0.00000438, 53.370857], [0.00000458, -146.0206], [0.00000479, 40.30661], [0.000005, -146.0206], [0.00000521, -146.0206], [0.00000542, -146.0206], [0.00000563, -146.0206], [0.00000583, 34.286007], [0.00000604, 34.286007], [0.00000625, 40.30661], [0.00000646, -146.0206], [0.00000667, -146.0206], [0.00000688, 49.849033] ... [0.02730583, 40.30661], [0.02730604, 34.286007], [0.02730625, 34.286007], [0.02730646, 34.286007]], color: "#003399", "name" : " " } ], "title" : { "text" : "Thu, Oct 26, 2023, 15:32:36" },plotOptions: { series: { showInNavigator: true, point: { events: { select: function () { var text = 'Ampl: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 4) + '</br>' + 'Time: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.x, 4); var chart = this.series.chart; if (!chart.lbl) { chart.lbl = chart.renderer.label(text, 75, 7).attr({ padding: 10,r: 5,zIndex: 0 }).css({color: 'red'}).add();} else {chart.lbl.attr({text: text}); } } , click: function (event) { this.select(!this.selected, false); } } }, marker: { enabled: true, radius: 0.1, states: { select: { fillColor: 'red', lineWidth: 0, radius: 4  }, hover: { fillColor: '#4da6ff', lineWidth: 1, radius: 6 } } } } }, "legend" : { "enabled" : false },"yAxis" : [ { "title" : { "text" : " dB SPL " }  } ],"xAxis": [{ min:0, "title": { "text": " min " }, "type": "none"   } ],tooltip: { formatter: function(){ return 'Ampl: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 4) + '</br>' + 'Time: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.x, 4) }, positioner: function() { return { x: this.chart.plotSizeX-120, y: this.chart.plotTop-45 }; }, shared: true, shadow: false, borderWidth: 0, backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.8)" }  ,navigator: { margin:10, enabled: true, series: {  dataGrouping: { enabled: false } } ,xAxis: { type: 'linear', labels: { formatter: function() { return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 2); } } } }, scrollbar: { enabled: true }}

Any help with resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

The series may appear blurred because there are too many points for your computer to handle. When I opened the demo I didn't see any blur. The chart is quite crowded with data, but as you zoom in, you should be able to see more details of the individual points.

@DominikChudy, I mean the series inside the navigator blurred when the chart loads initially. It disappears when you zoom in or out. There is no issue with the main chart.

Unfortunately in my case the series in navigator is still looking good. However you can experiment with dataGrouping option as it may affect the look of the series in the navigator.
